# how to prefix each line in textarea with number when it's in editable mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I googled this for a while now and had no luck finding something reasonable, and what I'm trying to achieve is something similar to this:

[image]

Just to note that the technologies I'm working with are angular, html 5 and css 3. I did find some jquery library/plugin but I was wondering if there is a way i could do this with the technology stack I'm working with and avoid jquery.

Comment: You can't control how native textareas are displayed. You should implement a fake one yourself, e.g. using contenteditable div. Or use an existing implementation like [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/).

Comment: maybe you can display two textarea stick together. the first (left one) display the line number, and the second (right one) is the normal textarea for editing

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library like [ace](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about)

Demo:

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

```css
#editor { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.2/ace.js"></script>

<div id="editor">function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After googling for while, I managed to find a library called [Behave.js](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Behave.js/), a lightweight library for adding IDE style behaviors to plain text areas, making it much more enjoyable to write code in. I've put a plunker to see it in action.

`plunker`